# Allow Parent .htaccess to redirect all assets

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache-2.4

We're migrating from one subdomain to another.  This particular domain has a subset of several websites.  I've setup the following rewrite to handle the redirect globally:

In `docroot/.htaccess` ("Rule #1")

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^virtual\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://events.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It generally works, except for a few sites which have their own rewrite rules.  For example, `/roadshow/2015/` has the following catch-all rule:

In `docroot/roadshow/2015/.htaccess` ("Rule #2")

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

**The problem:** Pages under `/roadshow/2015/` continue to load as if Rule #1 doesn't exist.

What am I missing here? :)

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess files in subfolders will trump ones in parent folders - try using `RewriteOptions Inherit` in each subfolder's .htaccess file (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions).

If you're running Apache 2.4.8 or higher, you can use RewriteOptions InheritDown to apply to all child .htaccess files automatically rather than having to modify each one.